# Jmeter: Where beanshell result is printed

Tags: logging, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I get this JSON response from my web service:

```
[
    {
        "type": "022",
        "sendDate": "2020-11-09 12:43:07",
        "message": "test1",
        "id": 8035,
    },
    {
        "notificationType": "023",
        "sendDate": "2020-11-09 11:40:02",
        "message": "test2 ",
        "id": 8034,
    },...
]
```

Now by Beanshell in JMeter i want to pass first `id` into new request so in JSR223 PostProcessor i write a simple print like this:

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.*;
String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
print("value "+ jsonString);
```

but when i run my rest test i got this :
[image]

Where is my print value?I expect to see my result on JMeter log viewer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.out` will print to console, if you want to print to JMeter's log use [log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) variable

```
log.info("value=" + jsonString);
```

> log - (Logger) - can be used to write to the log file

(Log viewer display jmeter.log)